# System.out.print producing correct result but looping through HashMap is not

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashmap

I am making a "general" fixtures generator. So you input names/teams etc and it creates a table of fixtures that need to be played.

When the "team" is entered they are entered into a hashmap, the reason for the int is each team has points, so everyone is defaulted to 0.

I am trying to create a way to making everyone verse each other once and i can do that via this method.

```
public HashMap<String, String> genFixtures(HashMap<String, Integer> m_playerList){
    HashMap<String, String> r_fixtures = new HashMap<String, String>();

    ArrayList<String> m_fixtures = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String key : m_playerList.keySet()){
        m_fixtures.add(key);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m_fixtures.size(); i++){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < m_fixtures.size(); j++){
            if (m_fixtures.get(i).equals(m_fixtures.get(j))){
                continue;
            } else {
                r_fixtures.put(m_fixtures.get(i) , m_fixtures.get(j));
            }

        }
    }
    return r_fixtures;
}
```

This creates a new hashmap with a string key and value as I want the hashmap to store each team, key being a team and value being a team(I feel like this is a very bad way to do this).
I then add all  keys of the original String,Int Hashmap to an ArrayList, perform an operation where they all get matched up with each other which works exactly as planned and then adds them to that String String hashmap and returns into to this method in a seperate class:

```
 if(e.getSource()== m_generate){
    HashMap<String, String> m_gend = new HashMap<String,String>();
    m_gend =  m_fix.genFixtures(m_playerList);
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m_gend.entrySet()) {
        String m_key = entry.getKey();
        String m_value = entry.getValue();
        m_labelNames.setText(m_labelNames.getText() + m_key + " v " + m_value + "\n");
        }
    }
```

but when I add the content of the hashmap to the JTextArea, lets just say I add the teams "Ceri", "Harry", "Matthew".
What gets outputted is

Matthew v Harry
Ceri v Harry

but no Ceri v Matthew.

Answer (score 0):

> when I add the content of the hashmap to the JTextArea, lets just say
>   I add the teams "Ceri", "Harry", "Matthew". What gets outputted is
>
> Matthew v Harry Ceri v Harry

Because [Hashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) doesn't preserve order of insertion. When you iterate on Hashmap entries you will get different different values

You can find that in documentation

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time

From [Oracle documention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: You could use the LinkedHashMap in order to preserve the order:     [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)